# DataTable INSERT/update в таблицу на сервер одним методом

Tags: c#

Подскажите, есть ли возможность сделать insert/update всей таблицы `DataTable` одним методом? не создавая
конструкцию строку в ручную типа `string = "insert into  table value" + "" + "...."`
Чтобы это все автоматом делалось. Заполнил таблицу на клиенте потом сказал `dataTable.saveToMSSQLServer`
Может есть сторонние известные классы от `DataTable`?

Сейчас делаю так

```
for (i = 0; i <= DS.Tables["CalcOp"].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                x.CommandString = "insert into CalcOp Values ( ";
                x.CommandString = x.CommandString + "{@CalcOpID},";
                x.CommandString = x.CommandString + "{@CalcID},";
                x.CommandString = x.CommandString + "{@CalcOpType},";
                x.CommandString = x.CommandString + "{@CalcOpName},";
                .....
```

Делаю в ручную. Хотелось бы этого избежать ручной работы.

Или писать самому?

Спасибо.

Comment: Вы ищете решение взамен того способа, который вам не нравится. Приведите конкретный пример такого кода, как можно ближе к реальности.

Comment: @ aepot добавил в первый пост. Сейчас в ручную формирую insert строку. Хотелось бы автоматизации. Идеально бы наследник от DataTable в котором уже все бы было сформировано в зависимости от структуры таблицы. Я вижу что делаю ерунду. Думаю писать свой наследник от datatable. Интересуюсь просто есть ли готовые решения.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите класс [SqlDataAdapter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter) и его метод [Update](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dataadapter.update).

Чтобы этот адаптер мог выполнить запросы, у него должны быть заданы свойства  `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand`, `DeleteCommand`. Они могут быть автоматически сгенерированы с помощью [DbCommandBuilder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommandbuilder).

Статьи по теме:
[Updating Data Sources with DataAdapters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters),
[Generating Commands with CommandBuilders](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/generating-commands-with-commandbuilders).

Comment: засчитаю ответ.. но написал свой класс который формирует из таблицы готовые запросы на INSERT UPDATE всей таблицы. Класс сам формирует запросы считывая колонки их типы и их значения. И сделал метод типа: myDataTable.SaveToServer.

Comment: @Manul74, вы можете сами опубликовать ответ на свой вопрос и даже принять его.